# Cannot sort the results of this php script descending

Tags: php

Hello I suspect I am being silly but I am new to PHP coding. All I want to do is sort my results from this script below in a descending order, but I don't know what code to add and where to add it. Please can you help me with this.

```
<?php
$d = dir("01-Newsletters");
while (false != ($entry = $d->read())) {
if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
echo "<tr><td>{$entry}</td><td><a href='01-Newsletters/{$entry}' target=_blank><img     src='../../Site_data/Images/more.gif'/></a></td></tr>";}
}
$d->close();
?>
```

Currently it is giving this result

```
Previous Newsletters 2014-04-Newsletter.pdf 

2014-07-Newsletter.pdf 

2014-10-Newsletter.pdf 

2015-01-Newsletter.pdf 

2015-04-Newsletter.pdf 

2015-08-Newsletter.pdf
```

Comment: You first will need to store every entry in an array and then sort this array using something like `usort($entries, function($a, $b) { return $a < $b; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
<?php
$d = dir("01-Newsletters");
$entries = [];

while (false != ($entry = $d->read())) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
        $entries[] = $entry;
    }
}
$d->close();

//order the entries...
sort($entries, SORT_STRING);
$entries = array_reverse($entries);

//output the $entries in DESC order...
for ($i = 0; $i < count($entries); $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$entries[$i]}</td><td><a href='01-Newsletters/{$entries[$i]}' target=_blank><img src='../../Site_data/Images/more.gif'/></a></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the folder name is 2015-8 I assume it is created on that particular day. On the basis of this assumption, you can use the following approach. Get files modified time store it in an array and then sort that array

```
$dir  = "jays";
$d = dir($dir);
while (false != ($entry = $d->read())) 
{
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
    {
        $files[$entry] = filemtime( $dir.'/' . $entry);
    }
}
arsort($files);
print_r($files);
$d->close();
```